# Capturing the definition of a LaTeX command in a Lua variable

Tags: macros, luatex, expansion

I'd like to get the meaning of a `LaTeX` command in fully expanded form in a lua variable.  What is the easiest way of getting there?  In other words, what should I be replacing the function `getmeaning` with?

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase}

\begin{luacode}
function whatis(s)
  s="\\" .. s
  x=getmeaning(s)
  end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\whatis}[1]{\luadirect{whatis(\luastring{#1})}} 

\begin{document}
I want the contents of \textbackslash{}foo fully expanded to appear in the Lua variable x.
\whatis{foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what would be your expectations of "fully expanded" for `\def\foo{\def\a{1}\def\b{\a}\def\c{\b}\the\numexpr\a+\b+\c\relax}` (to stay simple). What happens if `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\x\expandafter\string\b` is added to contents of `\foo`?

Comment: "fully expanded" doesn't have a general definition, you can put the `\meaning` into a Lua string simply by `\def\whatis#1{\directlua{s="\expandafter\luaescape\expandafter{\meaning#1}"}}...\whatis\foo`

Comment: Thanks @David.  I was hoping for something at the lua end, but perhaps this will do.  By fully expanded I meant whatever it is that edef does.

Comment: @JPi  yes but if you put a general latex command in an `\edef` you get an error message and no usable document. try `\edef\zz{\section{}}`  given that that gives a fatal error what yould you want `\whatis{\section}` to do?

Comment: I am aware of that.  Ulrike pointed that out on someone else's question a while back.

Comment: And basically, I'm mostly looking for ways to get the most out of the lua half of luatex.  That requires some learning on my part.

Comment: Do you know the answer without the requirement of “fully expanded”?

Comment: ^ Answering above comment: we can use `token.get_macro` or `token.get_meaning`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the replacement text of a macro with `token.get_macro` but full expansion (as far as it is defined at all) is something firmly on the tex side of luatex.  `\directlua` already does edef style expansion so that doesn't leave a lot for Lua to do other than save the resulting string in a global variable.

I show both forms here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
function whatis(s)
  x=token.get_macro(s)
  end

function whatisE(s)
  xe=s
  end

}

\def\foo{a \zzz\space b}
\def\zzz{XYZ}

\newcommand{\whatis}[1]{\directlua{whatis("#1")}} 
\newcommand{\whatisE}[1]{\directlua{whatisE("\csname#1\endcsname")}} 

\begin{document}
I want the contents of \textbackslash{}foo to appear in the Lua variable x.
\whatis{foo}

I want the contents of \textbackslash{}foo fully expanded to appear in the Lua variable xe.
\whatisE{foo}

x is \texttt{\directlua{tex.print(-2,x)}}

xe is \texttt{\directlua{tex.print(-2,xe)}}
\end{document}
```